# CSS background color not registering

Tags: html, css

Not really worried about the javascript part of this because I need to figure that out on my own, but something that generally works for me is not. My td.d and my td.f are not registering in the table and are just showing up with the  background color(white, but if I change the background color of the table it changes those settings as well)
I've run this in through a debugger and nothing is showing up and I've tried changing it around a few times, but nothing seems to make it use those css settigns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <style type = "text/css">
        table {width: 300px;
                    border-collapse: collapse;}
        table, td, th { border: 1px solid black;
                        padding: 4px;}
        th { text-align: left; color:white; background-color:red;}
        td.a  { 
                background-color: darkblue;}
        td.b  { 
                background-color: yellow;}
        td.c  { 
                background-color: orange;)
        td.d  { 
                background-color: #330000;}
        td.f  { 
                background-color: #00FF00;}

    </style>


    <title> Grades </title>

<script>
var grades = 0;
grades = window.prompt('Enter Scores seperated by a space');
if (grades == null || grades == "")
    {
    document.writeln("No graph to display");
    }
if (grades != null && grades != "")
    {
        array = grades.split(" "); //split up the string of grades into individual numbers by seperating with a space
        var lengthOfArray = array.length; // get length of array for use later in the for loop

        var letterCounter = new Array( 0,0,0,0,0 ); //make new array to be able to count the numbers of A's,B's,C's...
        for (var counter = 0; counter < lengthOfArray; ++counter) //implement the grade that pertains to the if statements
            {
                if (array[counter] >=90)

                        letterCounter[0]++;

                else
                    if (array[counter] >=80)

                            letterCounter[1]++;

                        else
                            if (array[counter] >=70)

                                letterCounter[2]++;

                                else
                                    if (array[counter] >=60)

                                            letterCounter[3]++;

                                        else
                                            if(array[counter] <60)

                                                    letterCounter[4]++;
                                                };

        document.writeln("<table>");
        document.writeln("<th>Grades</th>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='a' colspan=letterCounter[0]></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='b'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='c'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='g'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='h'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln(letterCounter);
        document.writeln(array);
    };



  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You might find this style more readable: http://jsfiddle.net/1ezpub5g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, you probably accidentally closed a statement by `)` (after `orange;`), you should be closing it using `}`. That is the reason the rest of the CSS code didnt work and the table didnt get styled as you expected.

I have added sample rows with the relavant classes for the demonstration below.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var grades = 0;
grades = window.prompt('Enter Scores seperated by a space');
if (grades == null || grades == "")
    {
    document.writeln("No graph to display");
    }
if (grades != null && grades != "")
    {
        array = grades.split(" "); //split up the string of grades into individual numbers by seperating with a space
        var lengthOfArray = array.length; // get length of array for use later in the for loop

        var letterCounter = new Array( 0,0,0,0,0 ); //make new array to be able to count the numbers of A's,B's,C's...
        for (var counter = 0; counter < lengthOfArray; ++counter) //implement the grade that pertains to the if statements
            {
                if (array[counter] >=90)

                        letterCounter[0]++;

                else
                    if (array[counter] >=80)

                            letterCounter[1]++;

                        else
                            if (array[counter] >=70)

                                letterCounter[2]++;

                                else
                                    if (array[counter] >=60)

                                            letterCounter[3]++;

                                        else
                                            if(array[counter] <60)

                                                    letterCounter[4]++;
                                                };

        document.writeln("<table>");
        document.writeln("<th>Grades</th>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='a' colspan=letterCounter[0]></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='b'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='c'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='d'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='f'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='g'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln("<tr><td class='h'></td></tr>");
        document.writeln(letterCounter);
        document.writeln(array);
    };
```

```css
table {width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;}
table, td, th { border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;}
th { text-align: left; color:white; background-color:red;}
td.a  { 
  background-color: darkblue;}
td.b  { 
  background-color: yellow;}
td.c  { 
  background-color: orange;} /* you had ) here */
td.d  { 
  background-color: #330000;}
td.f  { 
  background-color: #00FF00;}
```

Comment: AH there it is! thank you. You would think that would show up in a debugger :(

Comment: @TandyRayes It doesnt but you could use a CSS validator to check these kind of errors. Please upvote and mark this answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: ah okay I'll have to remember CSS validator in the future thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just close style of 
td.c  with } instead of )

like

td.c  { 
                background-color: orange;}